# Navigate menu with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

In the past when I opened a menu with a shortcut key (for example <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>) the menu itself would open.

Now the shortcut keys are displayed but the menu is not opened, this makes it way harder to remember the right shortcuts, and makes it impossible to learn new shortcut paths.

How do I change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

- go to **Help**
- select **Keyboard shortcuts**
- disable compatible keyboard shortcuts

[image: 0]

Comment: Great responce, but if i use this i lose the compatible shortcuts. Is there a workaround?

Comment: unfortunately no. this is the only thing that prevents it. you will need to make a choice. there are no workarounds